# How to install Neo4j on Centos red hat?

Tags: neo4j, centos, yum

Should i install it with "yum" command . I searched a lot but didn't find anything concerning the installation on Centos.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "experimental" yum repository for Neo4j with installation instructions [here](http://yum.neo4j.org/). Note that is experimental only and should not be used in production environments.

For a more stable / production environment follow the instructions for downloading Neo4j [here](http://neo4j.com/download/). More specific linux installation information (such as how to run Neo4j as a service) is available [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-installation.html#linux-install).

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best option is to install the tar file. You will need to make sure you have Java running on your system beforehand. After that you can follow the steps below.

#### first install wget if you don't already have it

`sudo yum install wget`

#### fetch the tar

`wget https://neo4j.com/artifact.php?name=neo4j-community-3.0.3-unix.tar.gz`

#### extract the contents

`tar -xf <PACKAGE_NAME>.tar.gz`

#### and now you should be able to run the bin

`bin/neo4j console`

Comment: You need to install java 8 and set JAVA_HOME as well.